# Product of power-law distributed random variables

Tags: probability-theory, slowly-varying-functions

Assume $X_1, X_2$ are iid. distributed in a way so that they have a survival function of the form $P(X_i>x)=L(x)*x^{-\alpha}$. Where $L(x)$ slowly varying function (defined by: $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{L(kx)}{L(x)}=1$ for all $k > 0$).

I want to investigate if the product $X_1X_2$ follows a power-law distribution (so has the same structure in the survival function).

I have seen a few people note that this seems to be true, but I can't find a proof and am currently unable to work it out myself.
I have started thinking about some ways to prove it, but I always run into trouble.

For example: Is the derivative of $L$ again a slowly varying function? (I believe it is, but I can not prove it). (This would give a way to describe the density of the product).

Edit: For further clarification. I am looking for the proof of Lemma 4.1 (1) in [https://web.math.ku.dk/~mikosch/Preprint/Anders/n094p171.pdf](https://web.math.ku.dk/%7Emikosch/Preprint/Anders/n094p171.pdf)
(I do not understand the proof cited)

Comment: I added a reference to a paper, for better understanding

Comment: Does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_of_the_product_of_two_random_variables#Derivation_for_independent_random_variables) help you?

Comment: @J.G. no not really. I know how to calculate product densities, but I am unsure about the properties of the density. (Especially on the properties of the derivative of $L(x)$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proof is given by [ON CLOSURE AND FACTORIZATION PROPERTIES OF SUBEXPONENTIAL AND RELATED DISTRIBUTIONS](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/2920028B49DA6FEF10CB903EBBA36B9C/S1446788700021224a.pdf/on-closure-and-factorization-properties-of-subexponential-and-related-distributions.pdf).

I will first provide a more expansive version of the proof of the corollary, but won't touch on the proof of Theorem 3, which can be found in the document linked.

In the following let $RV_\alpha$ denote the set of regular varying functions and $\mathcal{L}_\alpha$ the set of functions so that:

$$ F \in \mathcal{L}_\alpha \Leftrightarrow \forall y \in \mathbb{R}: \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1-F(x+y)}{1-F(x)} = e^{-\alpha y}$$

For the survival function of a distribution function $F$ write: $\overline{F} = 1 - F$.

Let $X^*$ and $Y^*$ be two independent non-zero random variables with distribution $F^*$ and $G^*$ respectively.
Write $H^*$ for the distribution function of the product of $X^*Y^*$

I want to proof: $\overline{F^*}, \overline{G^*} \in RV_\alpha \Rightarrow \overline{H^*} \in RV_\alpha$

Define $X := ln(X^*), Y := ln(Y^*)$

For the distribution functions of $X$ and $Y$ write $F$ and $G$.
$F(x) = F^*(e^x)$ and $G(x) = G^*(e^x)$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\overline{F}(x+y)}{\overline{F}(x)} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\overline{F^*}(e^xe^y)}{\overline{F^*}(e^x)} 
        = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{-x\alpha}e^{-y\alpha} L(e^xe^y)}{e^{-x\alpha}L(e^x)} \quad \text{ for some slowly varying function } L$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{-x\alpha}e^{-y\alpha} L(e^xe^y)}{e^{-x\alpha}L(e^x)} = e^{-y\alpha} \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{L(e^xe^y)}{L(e^x)}
   = e^{-y\alpha} \quad \Rightarrow \quad F \in \mathcal{L}_\alpha$$

And using the same argument $G \in \mathcal{L}_\alpha$.

With theorem 3: $(F * G) \in \mathcal{L}_\alpha$

$$(F * G)(k) = P(X+Y \leq k) = P(ln(X^*)+ln(Y^*) \leq k) = P(ln(X^*Y^*) \leq k) = P(X^*Y^* \leq e^k) = H^*(e^k) \\
        \Rightarrow H^*(x) = (F * G)(ln(x)) \quad \forall x > 0$$

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\overline{H^*}(tx)}{\overline{H^*}(t)} = e^{-\alpha ln(x)} = x^{-\alpha} \Rightarrow \overline{H^*} \in RV_\alpha$$